# Como executo um método no final de cada método de minha classe C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, método, eventos

Possou uma classe pai e outra filha e gostaria de executar um determinado método, como um evento, sempre no final de cada chamada dos método das classes filhas. 
Como posso fazer?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer amigo. No final de cada método, quer chamar outro método?

Comment: Simplesmente adicione manualmente o método ali no final, vai ficar mais simples. Se você quiser trabalhar com eventos vai ser bem mais complexo do que simplesmente adicionar a chamada ao método.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso chama-se [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) ([programacao orientada a aspectos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto)), um conceito ortogonal a OOP.

Em AOP, os metodos sao decorados com aspectos. Geralmente, existem 3 tipos de aspectos: aspectos que sao executados antes do metodo, durante o metodo, ou *depois* do metodo.

Infelizmente, C# nao suporta este paradigma nativamente.

No entanto existem 2 maneiras de usar AOP em C#.

### Opcao 1 - PostSharp

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) e' uma ferramente que permite decorar metodos com attributos que representam aspectos desse metodos. Durante a compilacao, PostSharp *injecta* o aspecto no corpo do proprio metodo.

Mas PostSharp e' uma ferramenta paga (com 45 dias de trial). Se isso nao for uma opcao, recomendo a opcao 2:

### Opcao 2 - Interceptors / Castle Dynamic Proxy

[Castle DynamicProxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx) permite criar dinamicamente (em runtime) um tipo que age como proxy de outro tipo. O proxy intercepta todas as chamadas feitas no target, e permite adicionar logica envolvendo a chamada.

No teu caso, como queres chamar um metodo (por exemplo, `CleanUp`) depois de todas as chamadas ao objecto, o interceptor seria algo assim:

```
public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //invocar metodo no target
        invocation.Proceed();

        //invocar aspecto
        MinhaClass obj = invocation.InvocationTarget as MinhaClass;
        if(obj != null)
            obj.CleanUp();
    }
}
```

O metodo `CleanUp` vai ser chamado depois de todas as chamadas a qualquer metodo da instancia da `MinhaClass` (desde que a instancia esteja decorada com o proxy).

Castle DynamicProxy funciona melhor quando usado em conjunto com o [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) como ferramente para injeccao de dependencias. Assim, todas as instancias da classe serao automaticamente decoradas com o proxy.

#### Acerca do DynamicProxy:

Este projecto e' muito popular. E' utilizado como base em:

1. NHibernate

   > For example, NHibernate, an object/relational mapper uses DynamicProxy to provide lazy loading of data without the domain model classes being aware of this functionality.
2. varias frameworks de mocking (como [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) e RhinoMocks) para gerar dinamicamente os mocks.
3. *IoC containers* (Inversion of control / injeccao de dependencias) como Castle Windsor e Ninject.

Na minha empresa usamos ocasionalmente para adicionar aspectos de "logging" a algumas classes, de modo que todas as chamadas aos seus metodos sejam registadas no EventViewer em modo de debug.

Com o DynamicProxy, podemos 1) separar completamente o logging da logica de negocio e 2) definir o logging num so sitio, e depois aplicar o interceptor a varias outras classes (DRY).

Mais:

1. [Introducao a AOP com Castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx)
2. [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)

Answer (score 1):

Usando um método genérico na classe pai:

```
public void Metodo<T>(T t) where t: IInterfaceClasseFilha
{
    MetodoAntes();
    Metodo(t);
    MetodoDepois();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi ao certo sua dúvida, mas, classe com eventos é dessa forma como exemplo abaixo:

***Classes com evento:***

```
public class Pai : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void Acao(int numbers);
    public event Acao Actions;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Actions(1000);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class Filho : Pai
{

}
```

***Utilizando:***

```
static void filho_Actions(int numbers)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(numbers);
}

Filho filho = new Filho();
filho.Actions += filho_Actions;
filho.Execute();
```

***Saída:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque implementar `IDisposable` e chamar o `SuppressFinalize` se a classe nao tem finalizer?

Comment: @dcastro, isso é um exemplo, e está correto o que eu fiz, lógico que quem vai usar deve ter bom senso e observar isso.

Comment: Neste caso especifico, achei que era muito importante retirar esse codigo da resposta. Um leitor que nao esteja familiarizado com `GC.SupressFinalize` pode achar que e' boa pratica chama-lo sempre que se implementa `IDisposable`, quando na verdade menos de 1% das implementacoes precisam de chamar o `SupressFinalize`, e so' em circunstancias *muuuuuito* especificas.

Answer (score 0):

Use a construção [try/finaly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). O código na construção finaly vai ser executado sempre, mesmo se ocorrer uma exceção em sua classe, por isso você deve prever o tratamento que deve ser dado adequadamente.